# Twig, subtract 2 dates

Tags: php, symfony, twig

How can I subtract two dates with twig ?

I have an ending date and a begining date and I want the difference between both.

For example for both date "2015-02-20" and "2015-02-13" I should obtain "7".

How can I do that ?

Thanks for help

Comment: Hi @Macbernie what you think about my solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First Solution (recommended)  "Use an existing library":**

You can use the [KnpTimeBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpTimeBundle)

In the Twig:
This compare with the current date:

```
{# Returns something like "3 minutes ago" #}
{{ time_diff(form) }}
```

This compare with the another date:

```
{# Returns something like "3 minutes ago" #}
{{ time_diff(form , to ) }}
```

**Second Solution  "Do it yourself":**

Make diff via php function:

```
$calcFrom = $from;

$calcTo = $to;
$now->diff($calcFrom)->format("%a")
```

And make it available via a [Twig extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) or directly in an helper method in the entity.

**Another possible solution** is to write register a [custom DQL Function](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html) to do the work in the repository

Hope this help