# How to get the hours between two dates Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig, twig-extension

I have some problem with twig dates. I have orders in my web app and I want to display some like "Alex ordered ... from this website before 2 hours" or something like that. I already found a solution for this problem but I can get only the days between two dates.

```
{% set order = getRandomOrder() %}
{% set datePost = order.createdAt %}
{% set today = "now"|date('d-m-Y h:m:s') %}
{% set difference = date(today).diff(date(datePost))%}
{% set leftDays = difference.days %}
```

Comment: Have you already see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28538326/2270041?

Comment: Oh right, thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twig, subtract 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538253/twig-subtract-2-dates)